# How can I import an ANTLR lexer grammar into another grammar using Gradle 2.10?

Tags: java, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I've been learning about ANTLR 4 with Terence Parr's *The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*, which I've been following so far using Gradle 2.10 and its built-in ANTLR plugin. However I'm having some trouble getting some code which I adapted from Chapter 4, pp. 38-41 to work properly with my Gradle build script. (The reason I'm using Gradle, rather than ANTLR directly, is because I want to eventually integrate ANTLR into a Java web application which I'm making for my dissertation, and I'd strongly prefer to use a build tool for this so I can automate the ANTLR-to-Java code generation process and easily manage my dependencies.)

I've created two ANTLR 4 grammars (which I've pasted towards the end of this question): **src/main/antlr/org/jbduncan/Expr.g4** (a standard grammar) and **src/main/antlr/org/jbduncan/CommonLexerRules.g4** (a lexer grammar), where *Expr.g4* depends on *CommonLexerRules.g4* via an `import CommonLexerRules` statement. But when I try to run `gradlew generateGrammarSource` at the command-line with my **build.gradle** (also pasted towards the end of this question along with my **gradle.properties**), I get the following error:

```
12:45:21: Executing external task 'generateGrammarSource'...
:generateGrammarSource
error(110): org\jbduncan\Expr.g4:3:7: can't find or load grammar CommonLexerRules
warning(125): org\jbduncan\Expr.g4:12:11: implicit definition of token NEWLINE in parser
warning(125): org\jbduncan\Expr.g4:13:6: implicit definition of token ID in parser
warning(125): org\jbduncan\Expr.g4:19:6: implicit definition of token INT in parser
:generateGrammarSource FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateGrammarSource'.
> There was 1 error during grammar generation

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.166 secs
There was 1 error during grammar generation
12:45:24: External task execution finished 'generateGrammarSource'.
```

Looking at this error message, it seems to me that Gradle's ANTLR plugin is able to find *Expr.g4* but is somehow not able to find *CommonLexerRules.g4*.

I've made an attempt to resolve this error using a couple of external Gradle plugins (https://github.com/melix/antlr4-gradle-plugin and https://github.com/Abnaxos/gradle-antlr4-plugin) instead of the built-in one, but when I tried each of them, they introduced their own problems which I wasn't able to resolve.

Using the ANTLR 4.5.2 jar downloaded straight from the ANTLR website *does* let me to compile my two grammars without problems, but as I discussed earlier this is a really undesirable option for me, as I'd have to compile my grammars manually whereas I believe Gradle could do it automatically for me.

My question is this: **How can I resolve the error above and get Gradle to import my lexer grammar into my other grammar?**

---

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

group = 'org.jbduncan'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
mainClassName = 'org.jbduncan.Application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:$antlrVersion"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
    testCompile "com.google.guava:guava-testlib:$guavaVersion"
    testCompile "com.google.truth:truth:$truthVersion"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
}

// Send all generated source code to a directory other than build/, to workaround an issue in
// IntelliJ IDEA where it fails to recognise source files in build/.
def generatedJavaSourcesDir = 'src/generated/java'

generateGrammarSource {
    arguments += ['-visitor']
    outputDirectory = file(generatedJavaSourcesDir)
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir generatedJavaSourcesDir
        }
    }
}

clean {
    delete generatedJavaSourcesDir
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    distributionUrl = "http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-bin.zip"
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
gradleVersion=2.10

# Dependency versions
antlrVersion=4.5
guavaVersion=19.0
junitVersion=4.12
truthVersion=0.28
```

**src/main/antlr/org/jbduncan/Expr.g4**

```
grammar Expr;

import CommonLexerRules; // includes all rules from CommonLexerRules.g4

@header {
    package org.jbduncan;
}

/** The start rule; begin parsing here. */
prog: stat+;

stat: expr NEWLINE # printExpr
    | ID '=' expr NEWLINE # assign
    | NEWLINE # blank
    ;

expr: expr op=('*'|'/') expr # MulDiv
    | expr op=('+'|'-') expr # AddSub
    | INT # int
    | ID # id
    | '(' expr ')' # parens
    ;

MUL: '*'; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV: '/';
ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';
```

**src/main/antlr/org/jbduncan/CommonLexerRules.g4**

```
lexer grammar CommonLexerRules; // note "lexer grammar"

ID: [a-zA-Z]+ ; // match identifiers
INT: [0-9]+ ; // match integers
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' ; // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS: [ \t] -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

**src/main/java/org/jbduncan/Application.java**

```
package org.jbduncan;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public final class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputFile = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : null;

    InputStream inputStream = (inputFile == null) ? System.in : new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(inputStream);
    ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.prog(); // parse; start at prog

    System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print tree as text
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ```import CommonLexerRules;``` instead of ```options { tokenVocab = CommonLexerRules; }``` ?

Comment: @KvanTTT: Simply because I wasn't aware of the existence of `options`, as I've not yet reached a point in the book where they are covered (if they are covered at all). I'm not going to test your suggestion just now as I'm going to bed, but I should have time tomorrow, so I'll let you know then if it works out for me.

Comment: @KvanTTT: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work for me. 

Swapping the import out for the options and running `gradlew clean build` produces an error, where it claims `src\generated\java\CommonLexerRules.tokens` cannot be found (even though I can visibly see it in my project folder on my machine).

Comment: tokens file is necessary for parser generation...

Comment: I wonder if Gradle's ANTLR plugin not being able to find either `CommonLexerRules.g4` or `CommonLexerRules.tokens` are related in some way... Do you have any other suggestions @KvanTTT?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about Grandle :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my question after posting it on the Gradle [forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-gradle-2-10s-antlr-plugin-to-import-an-antlr-4-lexer-grammar-into-another-grammar/14970):

```
generateGrammarSource {
  arguments << "-lib" << "src/main/antlr/org/jbduncan" 
}
```

where `"src/main/antlr/org/jbduncan"` is a path with your antlr `.g4` library.