# Create Java 8 AST with ANTLR4 programmatically

Tags: java, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to figure out just how exactly to use ANTLR, but I'm having a really difficult time digesting the things I've found. So far, here are my resources:

- [How to create AST with ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971097/how-to-create-ast-with-antlr4)
- [How can I import an ANTLR lexer grammar into another grammar using Gradle 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605634/how-can-i-import-an-antlr-lexer-grammar-into-another-grammar-using-gradle-2-10)
- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8
- https://dzone.com/articles/parsing-any-language-in-java-in-5-minutes-using-an
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/antlr4/master/doc/getting-started.md

#### A little bit of background

I'm experimenting with moving from [JavaParse](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) to ANTLR because I want to handle ASTs of languages besides Java. My understanding of ANTLR and the predefined grammars (linked above) is that this is feasible.

**Setup**

- IntelliJ 15 CE
- Gradle
- Java 1.8
- [This ANTLR resource](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.antlr%7Cantlr4-master%7C4.5.2-1%7Cpom)

I created a very simple and standard gradle project in IntelliJ and I'm still encountering issues:

#### The problem

I'm missing the `Java8Lexer` and `Java8Parser` classes. I have no idea where to find these.

`build.gradle`

```
group 'com.antlr-demo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.antlr:antlr4-master:4.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

[`Test.java`](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Test.java)

Even in this very trivialized example, none of the two classes I need are not being imported.

```
public static void parseFile(String f) { // found in Test.java:257
    try {
        if ( !quiet ) System.err.println(f);
        // Create a scanner that reads from the input stream passed to us
        Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(new ANTLRFileStream(f)); // missing

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        // Create a parser that reads from the scanner
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens); // missing
        if ( diag ) parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
        if ( bail ) parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());
        if ( SLL ) parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);

        // start parsing at the compilationUnit rule
        ParserRuleContext t = parser.compilationUnit();
        if ( notree ) parser.setBuildParseTree(false);
        if ( gui ) t.inspect(parser);
        if ( printTree ) System.out.println(t.toStringTree(parser));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("parser exception: "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();   // so we can get stack trace
    }
}
```

It's not described in the [pom file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/pom.xml)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one step. You got the java8 grammar but you haven't yet created a a parser from it. This usually involves running the antlr4 jar on the grammar file ([FAQs and more](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md)), which is very simple (example taken from the [Getting Started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) page):

```
$ antlr4 Hello.g4
$ javac Hello*.java
```

Comment: Well, that certainly answers my question

Answer (score 4):

I have created an open source project on github that does the parser/lexer generation and the AST creation automatically and in-memory. You can find it on github https://github.com/julianthome/inmemantlr.

The code for getting the AST from a JAVA program is pretty simple:

```
// the ANTLR grammar
File f = new File("src/test/ressources/Java.g4");
// plug the ANTLR grammar in 
GenericParser gp = new GenericParser(f, "Java");
// load the file that we'd like to parse into a String variable
String s = FileUtils.loadFileContent("src/test/ressources/HelloWorld.java");
// this listener will create an AST from the java file    
gp.setListener(new DefaultTreeListener());
// compile Parser/Lexer
gp.compile();
ParserRuleContext ctx = ctx = gp.parse(s);
// get access to AST
Ast ast = dlist.getAst();
// print AST in dot format
System.out.println(ast.toDot());
```

If you are interested, you could have a closer look at the test cases in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gradle plugin whose name is `antlr` to translate `g4` files into `java` files. You can get details of `antlr` plugin at `https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/antlr_plugin.html`

In addition, you can see the real project using `gradle + antlr`: `https://github.com/todylu/xcodeprojectParser`

- the dependency in antlr grammar project : `antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3"`
- the dependency in demo project : `compile "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3"`

By the way, It's better to install [ANTLR v4 grammar plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358?pr=) into Intellij Idea to assist you edit `g4` file.